# 2D angle between vectors. Negative for up and right?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, 2d, linear-algebra

I'm working on some 2d math, and I'm finding the angle I get between `up(0, 1)` and `right(1, 0)` to be `-90`, which unless I'm crazy or missing something here, seems wrong. I would expect `+90`. I'm hoping someone here can help give me a sanity check.

This is the implementation I'm using:

`GetAngle(a, b) = atan2(Cross(a, b), Dot(a, b))`

where:

```
Cross(a, b) = (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x)
Dot(a, b) = (a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y)
```

Comment: why not simply: `angle = acos(dot(a,b)/(abs(a)*(abs(b)))`?

Comment: If you're facing north ("up") and want to go east ("right"), you have to turn -90 (counterclockwise by a right angle), right? 

Comment: @AhmedFasih Yeah, I see what I'm assuming incorrectly now. Feels an awful lot like saying `If you want to walk forward, just take -5 steps by the toe-to-heel rule`. Man, I have to rewire my brain on this one.... ah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be -90 degrees because of the right hand rule. From your computation:

```
a = (0, 1)
b = (1, 0)
Cross(a,b) = 0 * 0 - 1 * 1 = -1 = sin(angle)
Dot(a,b) = 0 * 1 + 1 * 0 = 0 = cos(angle)
```

Therefore,

```
GetAngle(a,b) = atan2(-1, 0) = -90 degrees
```

Note that `atan2(y,x)` is `tan^-1(y/x)`. Your formula for `GetAngle` is based on the fact that the cross product is defined as `a X b = ||a||||b||sin(angle between a and b)` and the dot product is defined as `a . b = ||a||||b||cos(angle between a and b)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, so if I want a positive turn to be clockwise I have to change my cross product to be left-hand, correct? Is there a good reason why I shouldn't do this? (maybe it's just me who's confused by right handedness in 2d?)

Comment: @xoorath you could do this, but you will be against convention (and in the process change the definition for cross-product). It is better to just stick with the accepted right-hand convention.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but:

To compute the angle between two vectors in such a way that the sign tells you whether the other vector is to the right or left with (i.e. negative for it's to the left and positive it's to the right) you can compute the difference between two `atan2` and then correct them like this:

```
def angleVec2(d, v):

    a_1 = math.atan2(d[1], d[0])
    a_2 = math.atan2(v[1], v[0])

    diff = a_2 - a_1

    if diff < -math.pi:
        diff = math.pi-(abs(diff)-math.pi)
    elif diff > math.pi:
        diff = -math.pi+(abs(diff)-math.pi)

    return diff
```